# Bootstrap 4 tags input - Add tags only from the predefined list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), and [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) for making a multiple category selection option. I want to select multiple items **only** from the predefined categories listed in the `predefined_list`

Right now, whenever user type something in the input field the auto suggestion works(using the predefined_list)  and user can see suggested relevant category tag and, add them.

However, user can also add new/custom arbitrary category tags by manually typing it. Say, user typed 'Apple' or 'Banana'. The category list gets submitted with the custom items too. I want user to be restricted from adding new/custom category and only select from the existing auto suggested category.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="pf-title">Categories</span>              
    <div class="pf-field no-margin">
        <input id="category-input" name="category" type="text" data-role="tagsinput">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var predefined_list = ["Linux", "Mac", "Windows"]
    $('#category-input').tagsInput({
    'autocomplete': {
    source: predefined_list
    },
    trimValue: true,
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `freeInput: false` in the options

Categories

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var predefined_list = ["Linux", "Mac", "Windows"];
    $('#category-input').tagsInput({
        'autocomplete': {
            source: predefined_list
        },
        freeInput: false,
        trimValue: true,
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have a look at the Eventlisteners in the examples
>   https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

**ES6:**

```
$('#category-input').on('beforeItemAdd', (event) => {
  if(!predefined_list.includes(event.item)) {
     event.cancel = true;
  }
});
```

**ES5:**

```
$('#category-input').on('beforeItemAdd', function(event) {
  if(predefined_list.indexOf(event.item) === -1) {
     event.cancel = true;
  }
});
```

1. Start Eventlistener which catches the event **"before item gets added"**
2. If predefined_list doesn't include the item added set the cancel `variable` to `true` so it doesn't get added
3. Exists since ES6. ES5 works with indexOf (which returns -1 if there is no match)

Answer (score 0):

`$('input').tagsinput('add', 'Linux', 'Mac', 'Windows');`

`$('input').tagsinput('remove', 'Linux', 'Mac');`

`$('input').tagsinput('removeAll');`

Comment: Writing code to share solution is okay but you should also add description to elaborate code.